# AWS SQS message retention period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-sqs-queue-msgretentionperiod) the maximum SQS message retention period(`MessageRetentionPeriod`) is 14 days. After that time message will be deleted from the queue.

Is any way with SQS to not lose these messages after their retention period expired? For example, it is not clear or is it possible to use Dead Letter Queue for this purpose?

Comment: I am curious why this is an issue for you.  It is not within the typical use case for a message queue to leave messages in the queue for hours, much less several days.

Comment: I have millions of batch tasks which was estimated to take 1-2 months, I also need to keep the messages in queue after 14 days!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well 14 days is the max limit you can keep the message. After 14 days you can move that message to S3 Bucket for backup. Also there is a hack you can do with DLQ.

Here is a quick hack where you send that message back to the main queue. This is definitely not the best or recommended option.

1. Set the main SQS queue as the DLQ for the actual DLQ with Maximum
   Receives as 1.
2. View the content in DLQ (This will move the messages to the main
   queue as this is the DLQ for the actual DLQ)
3. Remove the setting so that the main queue is no more the DLQ of the
   actual DLQ

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question - in a what form messages will be backed up at S3 Bucket ? Is it an automatic process ?

Comment: No it is not Automatic you will have to use Cli to automate and to move that messages from SQS to S3

Comment: But AFAIK from AWS documentation, these messages going to be deleted so how to back up them after their retention period expired ?

Comment: No you have to do that before the retention period

Comment: @alexanoid You can use a polled Lambda function to check DLQ and backup the data into S3 bucket.

Comment: How will this work to increase retention period? below is what is written in AWS documentation ```The expiration of a message is always based on its original enqueue timestamp. When a message is moved to a dead-letter queue, the enqueue timestamp remains unchanged. For example, if a message spends 1 day in the original queue before being moved to a dead-letter queue, and the retention period of the dl queue is set to 4 days, the message is deleted from the dl queue after 3 days. .``` source - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Comment: Can you help me understnad which is the timestamp parameter on the message that is being referred to decided retention period.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to some answers or blog posts you can find on the web:

The `RedrivePolicy` is not impacting what will happen to your message if they expire (reached the RetentionPeriod of the queue).

AWS documentation is stating the message is deleted and there is never a mention about RedrivePolicy playing a role.

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Limits_and_restrictions

> Q: How long can I keep my messages in Amazon SQS message queues?
>
> Longer message retention provides greater flexibility to allow for
> longer intervals between message production and consumption.
>
> You can configure the Amazon SQS message retention period to a value
> from 1 minute to 14 days. The default is 4 days. Once the message
> retention quota is reached, your messages are automatically deleted.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html

> MessageRetentionPeriod – The length of time, in seconds, for which
> Amazon SQS retains a message. Valid values: An integer representing
> seconds, from 60 (1 minute) to 1,209,600 (14 days). Default: 345,600
> (4 days). When you change a queue's attributes, the change can take up
> to 60 seconds for most of the attributes to propagate throughout the
> Amazon SQS system. Changes made to the MessageRetentionPeriod
> attribute can take up to 15 minutes and will impact existing messages
> in the queue potentially causing them to be expired and deleted if the
> MessageRetentionPeriod is reduced below the age of existing messages.

So DLQ can't help you here, and after retention period is passed, your message is simply gone, I am afraid.

PS: One can argue the absence of indication is not enough to prove it, and we'll be right.

I am basing this answer also on a real life production events that occurred to me last week.